# Animate UITextView from right of screen to left of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a UITextView that is added inside a UICollectionViewCell.
I want to animate the UITextView from right of the screen to the left with some spring damping. The problem is when the text view animates it increases its width first and the moves it to the left side. This is quite interesting as the width is already fixed. Has anyone faced the same problem?

```
let topTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView();
        tv.textColor = UIColor.white;
        tv.backgroundColor = .red;
        tv.text = "Fast, secure banking \n on the go";
        tv.textAlignment = .center;
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                tv.isSelectable = false;
                tv.isEditable = false;
        return tv;

    }();

//Set left anchor to right of the screen
    var topTextViewLeftAnchor = topTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor);
            topTextViewLeftAnchor.isActive = true;
            topTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true;
            topTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  60).isActive = true;
            topTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true;

//Change the left anchor from right to left
    topTextViewLeftAnchor.isActive = false;
            topTextViewLeftAnchor = topTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor);
            topTextViewLeftAnchor.isActive = true;

    //Animate the UITextView
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.topTextView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Why you don't use affine transform translate instead?

Comment: How to use affine transform for a UITextView. Can you show me an example

Comment: Refer this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/146603/ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started-2). Raywenderlich explains it well. Hope it helps!!

Comment: @luckyShubhra I don't think the above link gives any solution to the above problme

Comment: Link doesnt directly addresses your problem . Although u could get brief idea regarding animation.

Comment: I have a good knowledge of animation. But this is a different type